# Flutter my google map isnt working or showing on release build

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I am using google map in my app and its working file also but the issue is when I create a release build map isn't showing I can see map shadow very little and the zoom control button but it's not visible Don't know what is happening when I run on debug mode it's working absolutely fine.

My code

```
Stack(
                children: [
                  GoogleMap(
                    mapType: MapType.normal,
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                        target: loading == false
                            ? currentPostion
                            : LatLng(1.0, 1.0),
                        zoom: 18,
                        tilt: 50),
                    markers:
                        Set<Marker>.of(markers.values), // YOUR MARKS IN MAP
                  ),
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Flexible(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18.0, 0.0, 18.0, 15.0),
                            child: Container(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                height:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                child: Center(
                                    child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      color: Color(0xfff5f6fb),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                        child: Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                          'EVENT SUMMARY',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                                              fontSize: 15,
                                              color: Color(0xff8f9ba8)),
                                        )),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Center(
                                      child: Container(
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                        width:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                                0.08,
                                        height:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                                0.08,
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Text(
                                                "01",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                                                    fontSize: 22,
                                                    color: Colors.white),
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(200),
                                          ),
                                          color: Color(0xffff8300),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      capitalize(widget.data['eventType']),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          color: Colors.black54),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                              0.01,
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .width *
                                              0.02,
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .width *
                                              0.02,
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                            child:
                                                Image.asset('images/Oval.png')),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .width *
                                              0.02,
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          widget.data['details']['telemetry']
                                              ['location']['address'],
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                                              fontSize: 14,
                                              color: Colors.black54),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ))),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))
                ],
         
 )
```

I try to wrap goole map on container also but its not working.

Screenshot:

[image]

it's showing this error when I debug on release mode

```
Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
```

Comment: Can you share screen shot of this issue when you test in release build?

Comment: @HarshChovatiya done

Comment: Are you using a restricted API key?

Answer (score 0):

I think your google map just doing fine if we are looking at the screenshot I think the mistake was a stack. Why you put another widget above google Maps? it will be covered the google map anyway. I think what you want to achieve here is to re-create a layout with a Google map on the top and a container on the bottom? CMIIW, if that's correct u can use Column instead of stack.

```
Column
- Expanded 
  - Google map
- Container
  - Your container child
```